# pacman loop problems, images do not show up/move

Tags: loops, pygame

ok so im doing a pacman task (have posted before bascialy pacman and ghosts move around the screen and pacman bounces off them, however when the mouse is clicked the ghosts bounce of him and change to a "Scared image" and as far as i can tell ive worked out my local errors etc. however now my code doesnt seem to show any sprites at all. when i move the frame and boundary codes at the end to the top they show up but all on one point of the screen with no movement. any advice please?

```
import pygame
from random import *

#Core values/images for game 
pygame.init()


#define ghost collisons in orignal mode to alter pacmans movement

def ghost_collision():

    pacman_velocity[0] = randint(-1,1)
    pacman_velocity[1] = randint(-1,1)
    if pacman_velocity[0] < 0:
        pacman = pygame.image.load(PACMAN_LEFT).convert()
    elif pacman_velocity[0] > 0:
        pacman = pygame.image.load(PACMAN_RIGHT).convert()
    return pacman_velocity

#define mode 2 as ghosts changing to scared and bouncing off pacman
def mode_switch():

    global blue_right, orange_right, pink_right,\
          red_right, blue, orange, pink, red
    global mode
    if mode == False:
        mode = True
        blue = pygame.image.load(GHOST_SCARED).convert()
        orange = pygame.image.load(GHOST_SCARED).convert()
        pink = pygame.image.load(GHOST_SCARED).convert()
        red = pygame.image.load(GHOST_SCARED).convert()
    else:
        mode = False
        if blue_right == True:
            blue = pygame.image.load(BLUE_LEFT).convert()
            blue_right = False
        else:
            blue = pygame.image.load(BLUE_RIGHT).convert()
            blue_right = True
    if orange_right == True:
        orange = pygame.image.load(ORANGE_LEFT).convert()
        orange_right = False
    else:
        orange = pygame.image.load(ORANGE_RIGHT).convert()
        orange_right = True
    if pink_right == True:
        pink = pygame.image.load(PINK_LEFT).convert()
        pink_right = False
    else:
        pink = pygame.image.load(PINK_RIGHT).convert()
        pink_right = True
    if red_right == True:
        red = pygame.image.load(RED_LEFT).convert()
        red_right = False
    else:
        red = pygame.image.load(RED_RIGHT).convert()
        red_right = True

PACMAN_LEFT = 'pacman-left.png'
PACMAN_RIGHT = 'pacman-right.png'
BLUE_LEFT = 'blue-left.png'
BLUE_RIGHT = 'blue-right.png'
ORANGE_LEFT = 'orange-left.png'
ORANGE_RIGHT = 'orange-right.png'
PINK_LEFT = 'pink-left.png'
PINK_RIGHT = 'pink-right.png'
RED_LEFT = 'red-left.png'
RED_RIGHT = 'red-right.png'
GHOST_SCARED = 'vulnerable.png'
BOUNCE_SOUND = 'Thump.wav'
SOUND = pygame.mixer.Sound(BOUNCE_SOUND)
WIDTH = 1200
HEIGHT = 800
BACKGROUND_COLOUR = 0, 0, 0
CAPTION = 'Pacman'

pacman_left = True
pacman_right = True
blue_right = False
orange_right = True
pink_right = False
red_right = True
mode = False

frame = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption(CAPTION)
pacman = pygame.image.load(PACMAN_RIGHT).convert()

#Sprites and defined boundaries
pacman_boundary = pacman.get_rect(center = (300,300))
pacman_velocity = [1, 1]
blue = pygame.image.load(BLUE_LEFT).convert()
blue_boundary = pacman.get_rect(center = (300,300))
blue_velocity = [-1, -1]
orange = pygame.image.load(ORANGE_RIGHT).convert()
orange_boundary = pacman.get_rect(center = (300,300))
orange_velocity = [1, -1]
pink = pygame.image.load(PINK_LEFT).convert()
pink_boundary = pacman.get_rect(center = (300,300))
pink_velocity = [-1, 1]
red = pygame.image.load(RED_RIGHT).convert()
red_boundary = pacman.get_rect(center = (300,300))
red_velocity = [1, 1]

finished = False
while not finished:
    pygame.event.pump()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            finished = True
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            mode_switch()


    #####################################################
# Boundary sets for all sprite's (could use list but lack skill and time)
if pacman_boundary.left < 0 or pacman_boundary.right > WIDTH:
    SOUND.play()
    pacman_velocity[0] = -1 * pacman_velocity[0]
    if pacman_velocity[0] < 0:
        pacman = pygame.image.load(PACMAN_LEFT).convert()
    elif pacman_velocity[0] > 0:
        pacman = pygame.image.load(PACMAN_RIGHT).convert()
    pacman_velocity[1] = randint(-1,1)

if pacman_boundary.top < 0 or pacman_boundary.bottom > HEIGHT:
    SOUND.play()
    pacman_velocity[1] = -1 * pacman_velocity[1]

if mode == False:        
    if pacman_boundary.colliderect(blue_boundary)\
       or pacman_boundary.colliderect(orange_boundary)\
       or pacman_boundary.colliderect(pink_boundary)\
       or pacman_boundary.colliderect(red_boundary):
        ghost_collision()

    #####################################################

if blue_boundary.left < 0 or blue_boundary.right > WIDTH:
    blue_velocity[0] = -1 * blue_velocity[0]
    if mode == False:
        if blue_right == True:
            blue = pygame.image.load(BLUE_LEFT).convert()
            blue_right = False
        else:
            blue = pygame.image.load(BLUE_RIGHT).convert()
            blue_right = True

if blue_boundary.top < 0 or blue_boundary.bottom > HEIGHT:
    SOUND.play()
    blue_velocity[1] = -1 * blue_velocity[1]

if mode == True:
    if pacman_boundary.colliderect(blue_boundary):

        blue_velocity[0] = randint(-1,1)
        blue_velocity[1] = randint(-1,1)



#####################################################

if orange_boundary.left < 0 or orange_boundary.right > WIDTH:
    orange_velocity[0] = -1 * orange_velocity[0]
    if mode == False:
        if orange_right == True:
            orange = pygame.image.load(ORANGE_LEFT).convert()
            orange_right = False
        else:
            orange = pygame.image.load(ORANGE_RIGHT).convert()
            orange_right = True

if orange_boundary.top < 0 or orange_boundary.bottom > HEIGHT:
    SOUND.play()
    orange_velocity[1] = -1 * orange_velocity[1]

if mode == True:
    if pacman_boundary.colliderect(orange_boundary):
        orange_velocity[0] = randint(-1,1)
        orange_velocity[1] = randint(-1,1)


#####################################################

if pink_boundary.left < 0 or pink_boundary.right > WIDTH:#
    pink_velocity[0] = -1 * pink_velocity[0]
    if mode == False:
        if pink_right == True:
            pink = pygame.image.load(PINK_LEFT).convert()
            pink_right = False
        else:
            pink = pygame.image.load(PINK_RIGHT).convert()
            pink_right = True

if pink_boundary.top < 0 or pink_boundary.bottom > HEIGHT:
    SOUND.play()
    pink_velocity[1] = -1 * pink_velocity[1]

if mode == True:
    if pacman_boundary.colliderect(pink_boundary):
        pink_velocity[0] = randint(-1,1)
        pink_velocity[1] = randint(-1,1)


#####################################################

if red_boundary.left < 0 or red_boundary.right > WIDTH:
    red_velocity[0] = -1 * red_velocity[0]
    if mode == False:
        if red_right == True:
            red = pygame.image.load(RED_LEFT).convert()
            red_right = False
        else:
            red = pygame.image.load(RED_RIGHT).convert()
            red_right = True

if red_boundary.top < 0 or red_boundary.bottom > HEIGHT:
    SOUND.play()
    red_velocity[1] = -1 * red_velocity[1]

if mode == True:
    if pacman_boundary.colliderect(red_boundary):
        red_velocity[0] = randint(-1,1)
        red_velocity[1] = randint(-1,1)


#####################################################


pacman_boundary = pacman_boundary.move(pacman_velocity)
blue_boundary = blue_boundary.move(blue_velocity)
orange_boundary = orange_boundary.move(orange_velocity)
pink_boundary = pink_boundary.move(pink_velocity)
red_boundary = red_boundary.move(red_velocity)
frame.fill(BACKGROUND_COLOUR)
frame.blit(pacman, pacman_boundary)
frame.blit(blue, blue_boundary)
frame.blit(orange, orange_boundary)
frame.blit(pink, pink_boundary)
frame.blit(red, red_boundary)
pygame.display.flip()


pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the formatting of your post is off, it looks like all of your game loop logic is now outside of the loop.  Remember that Python is sensitive to indentation, so all of the code starting with:

```
if pacman_boundary.left < 0 or pacman_boundary.right > WIDTH:
```

is not inside of the loop:

```
finished = False
while not finished:
```

All of your drawing code his happening after the game loop, so in its current form it will only be rendered once, right before `pygame.quit()` is called.